Where can I download QNX Momentics and the VirtualBox VM?
I'm new to QNX.  I have a free, non-commercial license and in my QNX Software Center and in the "Installed" tab, I have the SDP version 8.0 installed.
When I go https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/8.0/com.qnx.doc.ide.userguide/topic/about.html it mentioned "Starting the IDE".  But there isn't a link for a download in that section.  In the QNX Software Center, and I filter on "momentics", nothing is displayed as available.
In https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/8.0/com.qnx.doc.qnxtoolkit.user_guide/topic/quickstart_guide.html, It mentioned having QNX installed in a QEMU, VMware, or VirtualBox, but when I search the BB website and the QNX Software Center, there's no image results returned.
I searched in https://www.qnx.com/developers/community.html and really the only option to ask QNX questions is here in Stack -- the irc and news resources are not active.
Where can I download QNX Momentics and the VirtualBox VM?
